# jqueryui datepicker disables Ctrl-a with IE

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, datepicker

Having an issue similar to '“Select All” does not work with twitter bootrap modal and IE', answered by merv. (thanks much merv)

Fiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/lesouthern/5ked9/
In simple call of datepicker:

```
$('input').datepicker();
```

Before using datepicker, Ctrl-A works.

After Ctrl-A and Select all are disabled with IE (confirmed with IE8).

Do I turn off an event for datepicker, as done with modal? Tried many combinations of this with no luck.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This may be less of a solution, and more like a hack.. but hey, I'm working with IE8..

Here is the angularjs directive I wrote that solved the problem.

My datepickers are in modal dialogs, and on view of them datepicker is intialized, and when they close, datepicker gets destroyed, and the div it creates removed. This is the only way I have been able to restore ctrl-a in this environment.

Before datepicker is intialized, and after it's destroyed, Ctrl-A works in IE8. That's good enough for me.

```
<input class="span2 paused-until"
    datepicker-wrapper="{
        maxDate : getMaxDate()
    }"
    ng-change="error=false"
    ng-model="pausedUntil"
    name="Paused Until"
    size="16"
    type="text"
    ui-validate='{validFutureDate : validateDate}'
    ng-pattern="/^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})$/"
    required />




.directive('datepickerWrapper',function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function($scope,$element,$attrs) {
            $scope.$watch('modal.model',function(m) {
                var _attrs = $scope.$eval($attrs.datepickerWrapper);
                var maxDate = (typeof _attrs === 'undefined' ||
                        typeof _attrs.maxDate === 'undefined') ? 
                        null : _attrs.maxDate;

                //if the dialog is open, create the datepicker
                if(m) {
                    $element.datepicker({
                        minDate    : '+1d',
                        dateFormat : 'mm-dd-yy',
                        showOn     : 'button',
                        buttonText : '<i class="icon-calendar"></i>',
                        maxDate    : maxDate,
                        onSelect   : function(dateText) {
                            //assign the selection of the
                            //text to the element's model
                            $scope[$attrs.ngModel] = dateText;
                            $scope.$apply();
                        }
                    });
                }
                //else completely remove this element and generated div
                else {
                    $element.datepicker('destroy');
                    $('#ui-datepicker-div').remove();
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I found yet another way to this, to make the datepicker element inline, and toggle show/hide outside the datepicker module. This seems to not interfere with ie8 Ctrl-A

Comment: Also found this with autocomplete. Running the destroy command with this re-enables Ctrl A. There appears to be a jquery-ui issue around this. Am using 1.10.2